# Running a SQL Server Agent Job in 32bit on Automator

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

A quick summary of the problem and question:

In a SSIS job, I'm using excel files (2007-2010) as a destination.
In the SQL Server Agent Job I run this with the 32bit runner checkbox on, and with the Run64Bit thing in SSIS on false.

This works perfectly.
The issue is that we need to run this package in Automator, but the job keeps failing.

The DBA'er says it isn't possible to connect Automator with a SQL Server Agent Job.
Now I'm thinking about a Powershell script that triggers the package with a 32bit runner.

Is this possible, or is there an easier way to get everything to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do u think that is 32 bit and 64 bit compatibility issue while running package in SQL agent, depends on what package system you are using, permissions to the drive etc. Are you using file system (SSIS) in agent job ?

Comment: It is absolutely possible in SQL agent if you deploy package into sql server or use catalogues